# build facebook folly library error in WSL2

Tags: c++, facebook, folly

I am building facebook folly lib in WSL2 Ubuntu system.
But it failed.
My environment.

```
$ uname -r
5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

The error information.

```
[455/909] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/folly/portability/Time.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/folly/portability/Time.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DFMT_LOCALE -DFOLLY_XLOG_STRIP_PREFIXES=\"/home/orange/folly:/tmp/fbcode_builder_getdeps-ZhomeZorangeZfollyZbuildZfbcode_builder/build/folly\" -DGFLAGS_IS_A_DLL=0 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -I/home/orange/folly -I. -I/tmp/fbcode_builder_getdeps-ZhomeZorangeZfollyZbuildZfbcode_builder/installed/fmt-rSB7vI55d8xVge5xISAhmkhjh1Turjb5j37Mb9oEyJo/include -O2 -g -DNDEBUG   -g -std=gnu++1z -finput-charset=UTF-8 -fsigned-char -Wall -Wno-deprecated -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused -Wuninitialized -Wunused-label -Wunused-result -Wno-noexcept-type -Wno-nullability-completeness -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -faligned-new -fopenmp -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/folly/portability/Time.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/folly/portability/Time.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/folly/portability/Time.cpp.o -c /home/orange/folly/folly/portability/Time.cpp
/home/orange/folly/folly/portability/Time.cpp:278:2: error: No clock_gettime(3) compatibility wrapper available for this platform.
#error No clock_gettime(3) compatibility wrapper available for this platform.
 ^
1 error generated.
[457/909] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Command '['/usr/bin/cmake', '--build', '/tmp/fbcode_builder_getdeps-ZhomeZorangeZfollyZbuildZfbcode_builder/build/folly', '--target', 'install', '--config', 'Release', '-j', '3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
!! Failed
```

Just note `#error No clock_gettime(3) compatibility wrapper available for this platform.`

I have google it and find an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/1882).But no solutions.
Also, I have try to add `-lrt` parameter, not working.
If anyone knows how to fix it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: clock_gettime is in librt. Are you linking against this library? If not, try compiling with `-lrt`.

Comment: @kiner_shah yeah. I have tried it.But it just occur `clang warning linker input unused`，did not solve the problem, same error.

Comment: How did you try? Please edit the question, add an update section and add details there.

Comment: you could try [`FOLLY_FORCE_CLOCK_GETTIME_DEFINITION`](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/4a8837f3226152c2106be366ecae3a228cde4f45/folly/portability/Time.cpp#L37)

Comment: @kiner_shah My understanding is that adding `-lrt` to cmake

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks. I am new in C++, could you please tell me how to set `FOLLY_FORCE_CLOCK_GETTIME_DEFINITION` ？ just like a parameters ？

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html

Comment: **FIXED.** It work perfectly when I change **gcc version** form 9.4 to **10**